# IBM AlchemyAPI - create corpus/knowledge graph with my data and perform concept search

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I'd like to create a corpus with my data set. I'd like something similar to creating a corpus with documents in Watson Concept Insights, but I did not find the corresponding API in Alchemy. How do you create a corpus/knowledge graph using AlchemyAPI? The relation extraction works only on the input. Is there way to perform relation extraction on the corpus to get related concepts?

I already used Watson Concept Insights. The customer requirement is to use AlchemyAPI.

Comment: You **can't** train your corpus/knowledge graph with AlchemyLanguage.